# UIAlertView within mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:withError:

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uialertview

I will improve my iOS Programm by handling errors for loading a MapView. If there is no internet connection I will display an alert. But the the method *mapViewDidFailLoadingMap* will get called again and again so the UIAlert.
How can I achieve that the the Alert will only showed once?

```
- (void)mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView withError:(NSError *)error {
NSString *domain = [error domain];
NSInteger code = [error code];
NSLog(@"userInfo: %@", [error userInfo]);
NSLog(@"localizedDescription: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
NSLog(@"localizedFailureReason: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
NSLog(@"localizedRecoverySuggestion: %@", [error localizedRecoverySuggestion]);
NSLog(@"localizedRecoveryOptions: %@", [[error localizedRecoveryOptions] description]);

if ([domain isEqualToString:NSURLErrorDomain]) {
    if (code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Map Loading Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release]; 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If your program logic allows then you can set the delegate for the MKMapView object to nil when the failure/error occurs and it will stop sending failure/error messages to the delegate thereby preventing display of multiple alerts.

You can set delegate to nil within mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:withError method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BOOL` flag to ensure that the error is shown only once for the `MKMapView`:

```cs
- (void)mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView withError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (displayErrors) {
        // display the error...
        displayErrors = NO; 
    }
}
```

If you reset the flag in `viewWillAppear` for the corresponding view controller, the error will be shown once for every time the view is accessed:

```cs
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    displayErrors = YES;
}
```